# How to create link for string base64 blob unreadable

Tags: php

Hello can get string https://awhduawhdi.com/folderuser/file.zip,
y necesary string unreadable.
Example https://awhduawhdi.com/duiawhudigawudgawudg.
Show button download file no show url interni /folderuser/file.zip.
Grax!.

Comment: I have no clue what this question is about. Please add code, any errors you get and try to rephrase your question

Comment: no give code necesary code php link

Comment: You want to take a known piece of text (url in this case) and map it to something that doesn’t look like the original and can’t be revered to it except by you? There are two ways that I can think of. The easiest is to just create this arbitrary string manually and store it along with the ID. The more complicated way is to use some sort of encryption. Base 64 and hashing won’t help because you need to be able to reverse it.

Comment: no want show https://send-file.casacam.net/register/todo/register/cuentas/accounts/albert1999280/public/devtools-vnc-master.zip

Comment: try https://send-file.casacam.net/?!=9228f2cecb2a676285eb3713528f5601

Comment: how can I create an arbitrary string? Can you give a little example?

Comment: How do I not show the path where the file is saved?